# High level algorithm that MySQL MVCC uses to build the previous snapshot

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database, innodb, database-administration

From MySQL [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-multi-versioning.html) about InnoDB Multi-Versioning:

> Internally, InnoDB adds three fields to each row stored in the database. A 6-byte DB_TRX_ID field indicates the transaction identifier for the last transaction that inserted or updated the row. Also, a deletion is treated internally as an update where a special bit in the row is set to mark it as deleted. Each row also contains a 7-byte DB_ROLL_PTR field called the roll pointer. The roll pointer points to an undo log record written to the rollback segment. If the row was updated, the undo log record contains the information necessary to rebuild the content of the row before it was updated. A 6-byte DB_ROW_ID field contains a row ID that increases monotonically as new rows are inserted. If InnoDB generates a clustered index automatically, the index contains row ID values. Otherwise, the DB_ROW_ID column does not appear in any index.

However, I couldn't find any information about how exactly those hidden columns(`DB_TRX_ID`, `DB_ROLL_PTR` and `DB_ROW_ID`) are used for building the previous snapshot, what's the algorithm ?

The [other page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-performance-ro-txn.html) in manual about read-only transaction states the following:

> InnoDB can avoid the overhead associated with setting up the transaction ID (TRX_ID field) for transactions that are known to be read-only. A transaction ID is only needed for a transaction that might perform write operations or locking reads such as SELECT ... FOR UPDATE. Eliminating unnecessary transaction IDs reduces the size of internal data structures that are consulted each time a query or data change statement constructs a read view.

Taking into account the above statement, as read-only transactions don't have associated `TRX_ID`, then there should be something else related to the current transaction that is compared to `DB_TRX_ID` value of the existing rows to be able to determine whether that particular row should be included in the built snapshot or not.

Please describe the high level algorithm and also about the case of read-only transactions if it makes the process different.

Answer (score 1):

If there are multiple connections modifying the same row, then there are multiple incarnations of the row in the "history list" for that row.  The `TRX_ID` controls the visibility:  If an incarnation is older than X, then the Connection can "see" it.  Else, it is a version (think the V in MVCC) that is not yet visible to *this* connection.  (Note:  `transaction_isolation` level gets factored into the 'visibility'.)

I suspect that `DB_ROLL_PTR` (think `ROLLBACK`) is only needed when a `ROLLBACK` is asked for (or a crash calls for it).

I would guess that a readonly transaction uses a `TRX_ID`, but not does not create a new one, since it won't be creating any new values to save in the history change, or to rollback.

For more gory details (and for checking the validity of what I have said), see [*blogs by JCole*](https://blog.jcole.us/innodb/) .